At what age do you start addressing people by family names
I know Japanese people go by their family names, unless they are really close or family. But small children seem to be called by their given names by default in what I've read/ seen. So at what age is the switch between calling someone by their given name, to their family name? I'm writing a fic with an 11-12 year old, and I'm not sure how she should be addressed

This is a nuanced topic that's not easy to explain simply.
First, for childhood friends who have known each other since very young, they may continue using given names throughout their relationship. The following mainly applies to ordinary classmates and club activity peers.

Kindergarteners primarily use given names to address one another, presumably because that's how their parents address them.
Around elementary school entry, teachers instruct students to address classmates as "family-name + san/kun". Recently, some elementary schools have started to mandate "-san" for all students regardless of gender, though this practice remains controversial.
By the upper elementary grades, most students use "family name + san/kun" by default, with given names reserved only for very close friend groups.
Around the teenage years, some students start using given names again. This happens earlier among more outgoing or socially-confident students addressing same-gender peers. More introverted students, those who speak politely, or those addressing the opposite gender tend to stick to family names longer. The psychological barrier of using given names can be very high to them. In manga featuring these age groups, you can guess a character's personality based on whether they primarily use family or given names. And some people simply don't want to be called with their given names. This is why some anime fans like to create and maintain 呼称表 like this.
By university age, naming conventions largely follow adult social norms, but they usually adopt the use of given names quickly once they become personal 仲間.

So the switch from given to family names happens around the age 6, and the opposite happens gradually from 12 to 18.
As for characters around 11-12, age alone isn't enough information to determine what would be most natural. If the characters have a long-standing friendship like the characters in Doraemon, using given names would feel natural. If they're just regular classmates, it would depend on their individual personalities, though since they're still in elementary school, family names would be much more common in the real world.
